Invalid Record turn on Edit mode - Moodle 4.3
I recently upgraded Moodle to version 4.3, but the Edit mode option is showing an error when I try to activate it. The platform update didn't show an error; in the previous version, 3.9, it was working normally. As this is a core module of the system, what solution should be adopted?
SELECT * FROM {external_functions} WHERE name = ?
[array (
  0 => 'core_change_editmode',
)]
Error code: invalidrecord
* line 1658 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_missing_record_exception thrown
* line 1634 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_select()
* line 56 of /lib/external/classes/external_api.php: call to moodle_database->get_record()
* line 186 of /lib/external/classes/external_api.php: call to core_external\external_api::external_function_info()
* line 83 of /lib/ajax/service.php: call to core_external\external_api::call_external_function()

I've debugged the variables and I think this plugin is missing from the 'external_functions' table, but I haven't seen how to fix it

Seems odd that the record is missing - The core_change_editmode service was added for Moodle 4.0
commit 09f6ce9fed752e47fc719228032aab075c526c09
Author: Bas Brands <bas@moodle.com>
Date:   Tue Jul 6 10:01:05 2021 +0200

    MDL-71610 theme_boost: add a edit mode switch

The record should have been created during the upgrade to 4.3
I would try a re-run of the upgrade on a local/development site with a backup of the 3.9 site. But switch on debugging to developer level and check for errors.
In config.php add
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!

If there are no errors, then check if the record exists after the re-run
SELECT *
FROM mdl_external_functions
WHERE name = 'core_change_editmode'

If it doesn't exist, then there is an issue with Moodle
If it does exist, then something has happened since the upgrade

I ran the command SELECT and confirmed that this service is not created in the mdl_external_functions table. Is it possible to add this service manually? Without having to redo the whole migration process from Moodle 3.9?

Was this after testing a re-run of the upgrade?
